# Understanding Eval Monad's `rpar`

Tags: haskell

Looking at the following example from [Parallel and Concurrent Programming in Haskell](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000929/ch02.html#sec_par-rpar-rseq):

```
main = do
  [n] <- getArgs
  let test = [test1,test2,test3,test4] !! (read n - 1) 
  t0 <- getCurrentTime
  r <- evaluate (runEval test)
  printTimeSince t0
  print r
  printTimeSince t0


test1 = do
  x <- rpar (fib 36)
  y <- rpar (fib 35)
  return (x,y)
```

The book shows its compilation:

```
 $ ghc -O2 rpar.hs -threaded
```

And then running the above test:

```
$ ./rpar 1 +RTS -N2
time: 0.00s
(24157817,14930352)
time: 0.83s
```

If I understand correctly, the Eval Monad (using `rpar`) results in both `fib 36` and `fib 35` being computed in parallel.

Does the actual work, i.e. computing the function `fib ...`  occur when calling `(runEval test)`? Or perhaps `evaluate ...` is required? Or, finally, perhaps it gets computed when calling `print r` to evaluate it entirely?

It's not clear to me **when** the actual work gets performed for `rpar`.

Comment: Probably when `print` is called? since your first print shows no time elapsed for the line `r <- evaluate (runEval test)` and 0.83s for `print r`.

Comment: When you use `evaluate`, you evaluate the argument to [weak head normal form](https://wiki.haskell.org/Weak_head_normal_form). The expressing `(x,y)` is already in WHNF, so there is nothing to evaluate! Since you haven't demanded the values of `x` and `y` themselves yet, they won't be evaluated. Then the call to `print` forces the evaluation of `x` and `y` to normal form, which in turn sparks the parallel computation you expect.

Comment: @user2407038 - thanks. Care to post for credit?  I think it deserves an answer post, not a comment alone.

Answer (score 5):

Here's my guess, but I can't seem to replicate this on my laptop, too many imports I'd have to get from cabal.

```
test1 = do
  x <- rpar (fib 36)
  y <- rpar (fib 35)
  return (x,y)
```

In this, you spark the evaluation of `(fib 36)` and `(fib 35)` in parallel, but you don't wait for them - you just return `(x,y)` immediately, while `x` and `y` are still evaluating. Then, we you get to `print r`, you are forced to wait until `x` and `y` finish evaluating.

In theory, the following code should force `test1` to wait until `x` and `y` have finished evaluating before returning them.

```
test1 = do
  x <- rpar (fib 36)
  y <- rpar (fib 35)
  rseq x
  rseq y
  return (x,y)
```

Then, running this should give you approximately

```
$ ./rpar 1 +RTS -N2
time: 0.83s
(24157817,14930352)
time: 0.83s
```

hopefully...

### EDIT

Finally got back to my machine, replicated the condition, and my suggested code gives the expected result. However, the OP raises another good question: if `evaluate` only evaluates to the WHNF, why does it even end up doing work before print is called?

The answer is in the [monad definition](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parallel-3.1.0.1/docs/src/Control-Parallel-Strategies.html#Eval) of `Control.Parallel.Strategies` - in other words, it isn't `evaluate` that pushes the evaluation of `x` and `y`, but `runEval`. The `Eval` monad is strict in the first argument: in `x >>= f` it will evaluate `x` (please check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11831156/how-does-the-bind-operator-for-eval-in-control-parallel-strategies-evaluate-its) before continuing). Then, de-sugaring `test1` gives:

```
test1 = (rpar (fib 36)) >>= (\x -> 
        (rpar (fib 35)) >>= (\y ->
        (rseq x)        >>= (\_ ->
        (rseq y)        >>= (\_ ->
        return (x,y)))))
```

Then, since `rpar` only "sparks" evaluation, it uses [`par`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parallel-2.2.0.1/docs/Control-Parallel.html) (which begins the evaluation of the first argument but immediately returns the second) and immediately returns `Done`, however, [`rseq`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parallel-2.2.0.1/docs/Control-Parallel.html) (like `seq`, but strict only in the first argument) does not return `Done` until its argument is actually evaluated (to WHNF). Hence, without the `rseq` calls, you have know that `x` and `y` have begun to be evaluated but no assurance that they have finished, but with those calls, you know both `x` and `y` are also evaluated before `return` is called on them.

Comment: From the above book's link: `The evaluate function is like a seq in the IO monad: it evaluates its argument to weak head normal form and then returns it:`. I interpret that to mean that, when calling `evaluate (runEval test)`, it gets evaluated to weak head normal form. I don't understand how that means that `rpar (fib 35)` and `rpar (fib 36)` are running in the background as a result of the call to `evaluate`.

Comment: @KevinMeredith Let me know if the edit answers your question fully.